# difference between find_in_set and and locate

Tags: mysql

I have product tables in my database

**Product table structure:**

```
product_id     |     testid
------------------------------------
   1                     11,12,13
   2                     2,4
```

**Below is my `FIND_IN_SET` query:**

```
SELECT product_id FROM product
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, testid) > 0;
```

**Output**

```
0
```

**Below is my `LOCATE` query:**

```
 SELECT product_id FROM product
    WHERE LOCATE(3, testid) > 0;
```

**output**

```
1
```

**My question**

What is difference between `FIND_IN_SET` and `LOCATE` and what is the best way to find id in `column`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between `LOCATE()` and `FIND_IN_SET()` Function

When using `LOCATE()` function for integers, suppose we need 1 to return from `LOCATE()` if integer 3 is in the set `1,2,3,4,5,..` the following MySQL commands can be written:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(LOCATE(3,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9')>0,1,0);
+-----------------------------------------+
| IF(LOCATE(3,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9')>0,1,0) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       1 | 
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

The above command working rightly because the set contains the number 3 , but if we write the following commands, look what happened

```
mysql> SELECT IF(LOCATE(3,'11,12,13,14,15')>0,1,0);
+--------------------------------------+
| IF(LOCATE(3,'11,12,13,14,15')>0,1,0) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 | 
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Above the 3 is not present as a number three(3) in the given set, though the `LOCATE()` returns 1.
To avoid this type of situation you can use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function. Here is the example below:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(FIND_IN_SET(3,'11,12,13,4,5,6,7,8,9')>0,1,0);
+-------------------------------------------------+
| IF(FIND_IN_SET(3,'11,12,13,4,5,6,7,8,9')>0,1,0) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               0 | 
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

So, LOCATE() function is very much suitable for string but not as much suitable for integer.

Examples, credits and some more information you can find [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

So in your example `FIND_IN_SET` return `0` because there is no `3` in the given set, but `LOCATE()` returns `1` it treat the given set as a string but not a comma separated value, and the `3` present in the number `13`

Answer (score 5):

To put it in simple technical terms(PHP terminology), find_in_set is like substring function of PHP. It will accept a substring and a string as parameters, and return 1 if the substring is found within the string. It will return 0 if substring is not found.

On the contrary, LOCATE() returns the position of the first occurrence of a string within a string. It accepts, a substring and a string as parameters.

I think in your use case, find_in_set is the one you should go for. Because this is the one. find_in_set will return 1 if 3 is found in a row, where as locate will first occurance of 3 in the string even if it finds 31 or 300 as first element.